# Kill remote process via ssh

Tags: ssh, process, quoting, kill, remote

I have a process that I want to kill remotely. I tried

```
ssh remotehost "kill -9 $(ps -aux | grep foo | grep bar | awk '{print $2}')"
```

but this returns the error

```
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

However if I run the command within the quotation marks

```
kill -9 $(ps -aux | grep foo | grep bar | awk '{print $2}')
```

on the remote host it works fine. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$(..)` command substitution would fail as the `$` is expanded by the local shell even *before* it is passed to the `stdin` of the `ssh` command. You either need to escape it or use here-strings.

Also the command inside the `awk` that prints `$2` gets interpolated as a command-line argument. So we escape it to defer its expansion until the command is executed remotely.

With escaping,

```
ssh remotehost "kill -9 \$(ps -aux | grep foo | grep bar | awk '{print \$2}')"
```

or with here-doc

```
ssh remotehost <<'EOF'
kill -9 $(ps -aux | grep foo | grep bar | awk '{print $2}')
EOF
```

Also note that `grep .. | grep .. | awk` is superfluous. You can do the whole operation with `awk` alone. Or even better use `pkill` to get the process to kill directly by name.

Comment: ah, interesting. I thought it would ship the complete expression within the quotation marks just as it is. So the $ will be evaluated immediately?

Comment: @chrise: In that case, it is preferred to use the second approach involving here-doc

Comment: either way I try seems to not return. So if I run it from command line, it doesnt go back to the prompt. If I run it from a script it doesnt go to the next line. Do I need to somehow explicitly exit this?

Comment: @chrise: You should use the here-docs carefully. There shouldn't be any leading spaces in the line after `'EOF'`, any leading spaces should be removed

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to kill for a set of hosts:

```
for i in `cat hostlist`;do ssh -q $i kill `ssh -q $i ps -ef | grep <process name>|awk '{print $2}'`;done
```

Answer (score 0):

you can optionally do something like

```
ssh remotehost "killall -r 'foo.*bar'"
```